# Clicking on the frequently changing content

Tags: javascript, html

there is a `<table>` with not many rows (hundreds) and one column in that table includes a link: `<tr> ... <td><a href='site.com'> site </a></td> ... </tr>`. My web application is characteristic of fast changing content - for example, every 100ms there is a refresh - getting new information from server ( `fetch("server")` -> `json()` -> `drawTable()` ). But usually only some cells inner html change, the link is usually unchanged.

My current quite naive solution rewrite whole table. There is not many content so my solution is fast enough. But problem is that it is not posible to click on the link (nor button) because table is almost always changing.

I have an idea to update only cells that actually change. Any other idea?

Thanks

Comment: Why You change table so often? Maybe You should just update some columns? Links are standard without any extra event?

Comment: This is a perfect use case for react or mobx as they only change the parts of the DOM that *really* need to change.

Comment: "is that it is not posible to click on the link (nor button) because table is almost always changing." You mean because you can't click on it fast enough? Don't update so often then, you'll give your users a headache.

Comment: Well it is an application for scientific purpose and the website lets users to change the interval. Standart interval is 1000ms which is ok, but there is a posibility that user needs faster reloading - my app is also drawing charts and smaller interval means more precise chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented my idea of updating changed cells and it works well. Created function `update()` and hold array from previous update:

```
 for ( let i = 0 ; i < rows.length ; ++i){
        const cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")
        for(let j = 0 ; j < cells.length ; ++j){
            if ( Arr[i][j] == ArrPrev[i][j] ) 
                continue
            else
                cells[j].innerHTML = Arr[i][j]
        }
    }
```